# Retrieving city statistics (Any API's or Databases?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, city

What I am looking to do is retrieving city statistics. Much like the CIA World Factbook. But, I want an API, database or dataset that I can query and get results. Also, I would actually PREFER to use a `UIWebView` and load a website with those statistics already searched and displayed. Like TheWeatherChannel for instance, I can form a URL with given coordinates. But websites like the CIA World Factbook have a unique two letter code for each country, which are not in a particular format.

Also, I would like to get CITY statistics, this would include:

- Population
- Crime Rate
- Description
- Languages Spoken
- Transport Systems
- Geography

and more! I even had an idea to show the type of plugs that country uses. But, I have no idea how and where to look for information like this.

Please help me out...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're asking for very generic data sets and APIs, so you may want to being exploring http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_data, https://explore.data.gov/, and http://www.freebase.com/

Answer (score 1):

A little late and it probably doesn't do city level but

http://data.worldbank.org/developers/data-catalog-api

could also be useful for someone looking for similar stuff and it wasn't mentioned (AFAICS) in the above answer's links.

This data also has a drupal module at

https://drupal.org/project/wbapi